# How do I mock a legacy object in this code below?

Tags: java, mockito

I have been writing unit tests using mockito framework.
I have this below legacy code, how do I mock the RemoteService client object in the approvalAction method without refactoring it?

```
public Map<String, String> approvalAction(long documentId, ActionCommandDTO request, FormData formData, byte[] prevData) {

    RemoteService client = getRemoteService();
    String urlString = String.format("formExtensions/%s?%s", formData.getId(), getAuthParam(formData.getRealm()));
    try {
        response = client.postEntity(urlString, String.class, approvalSvcRequestStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle rollback properly for P2P
        handleApprovalActionFailed(documentId, request, formData, prevData);
    }

    return map;
}


private RemoteService getRemoteService() {

    RemoteServiceConfig remoteServiceConfig = (RemoteServiceConfig) this.serviceConfigRegistry.getServiceConfigs().get("approval");
    remoteServiceConfig.setClientID(clientId);
    remoteServiceConfig.setClientSecret(privateSecret);
    RemoteService remoteService = new RemoteService(remoteServiceConfig, authorizationHeaderServiceImpl);

    return remoteService;
}
```

Comment: why would you change the code of your business logic in order to mock a service in a test?

Comment: @Stultuske, In some cases: while writing unit tests and covering test scenarios, We can find some problematic points in the business logic. Thus it may be reasonable to refactor the code while considering the test cases. Good unit tests are helping to make the architecture better

Comment: Not easily. Why do you include the constraint "without refactoring"?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan if you go test driven development, your tests are written before your implementation. that being said, we're not talking about code that is (by tests shown to be) malfunctioning, we're talking about changing the business code to allow the tests to run.

Comment: RemoteService needs to be wrapped behind an interface and used via this interface. Then you can write unit tests via the mock of this `IRemoteService` interface

Comment: An ugly solution would be to make getRemoteService package private then `spy` the class you are testing and mock it.

Comment: How about using `PowerMock` to mock the `RemoteService`? `PowerMockito` to be precise for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the `RemoteService` injectable via the constructor, but also allow a default constructor?

```
class YourClass{

    private final RemoteService client;

    public YourClass(RemoteService client){
        this.client = client;
    }

    public YourClass(){
        RemoteServiceConfig remoteServiceConfig = (RemoteServiceConfig) this.serviceConfigRegistry.getServiceConfigs().get("approval");
        remoteServiceConfig.setClientID(clientId);
        remoteServiceConfig.setClientSecret(privateSecret);
        client = new RemoteService(remoteServiceConfig, authorizationHeaderServiceImpl);
    }

    // all of your other methods inside the class

}
```

> Of course you'd have to adapt your already existing constructors. but as you've not shown the whole class this is impossible for me.

This leaves you with a single instance of a client throught the whole lifetime of `YourClass`.

---

Now it's very easy to mock the the `RemoteService`. Just instantiate `YourClass` with the mocked client:

```
RemoteService mock = mock(RemoteService.class);
YourClass toTest = new YourClass(mock);
```

Answer (score 0):

change `getRemoteService` to `protected`, and use subclass to override it:

```
public class SomeService {

    public Map<String, String> approvalAction(long documentId, ActionCommandDTO request, FormData formData, byte[] prevData) {

    }


    // change here
    protected RemoteService getRemoteService() {

        RemoteServiceConfig remoteServiceConfig = (RemoteServiceConfig) this.serviceConfigRegistry.getServiceConfigs()
                .get("approval");
        remoteServiceConfig.setClientID(clientId);
        remoteServiceConfig.setClientSecret(privateSecret);
        RemoteService remoteService = new RemoteService(remoteServiceConfig, authorizationHeaderServiceImpl);

        return remoteService;
    }

}


public class TestSomeService extends SomeService {


    @Override
    protected RemoteService getRemoteService() {
        return new MockService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock RemoteService because it's getting created inside your class. If possible extract getRemoteService to another class lets call it NewClass. Now you can mock NewClass.

```
public Map<String, String> approvalAction(long documentId, ActionCommandDTO request, FormData formData, byte[] prevData) {

    RemoteService client = NewClass.getRemoteService(params);
    ///
}
```

Other way is if you don't want to change your legacy code much is to extend your class(which implements approvalAction) override getRemoteService() function. In new implementation of getRemoteService call create mock RemoteService. You can than test this new class.